# Decoding JSON from Google Finances

Tags: php, json, api

I know Google Finances has been discontinued but I found this link to be still working and doing just what I need:
[CLICK](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:CLNS-D&output=json)

Now apparently it returns a file called **f.txt** which I do not know how to read through PHP. I tried this:

```
            $url = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:CLNS-D&output=json"
            $json = file_get_contents($url);
            $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
            var_dump($json_data);
```

But it doesn't work for me. The return of the var_dump is just NULL.

Can somebody please guide me to be able to interract with this **f.txt** file and be able to display data from it in my html?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code lacks error checking. Also, you should have extracted an MCVE before posting. here.

Comment: var_dumping $json instead shows that what this contains starts with 
line break, `// [`, line break, `{ ...` - so it clearly isn't JSON.

Comment: @CBroe oh, so you mean the f.txt file that comes from Google isn't JSON formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a JSON expert by any means, but it looked like the data you were retrieving from Google had a few leading characters that didn't look "standard". Stripping those solved the problem:

```
$url = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:CLNS-D&output=json";

$request = file_get_contents($url);
$data = substr($request, 4);
$json = json_decode($data, 1);

var_dump($json);
```